# How to make a new Angular 17 project run?

Tags: angular

Fresh installation of Nodejs (20.10.0) and Angular (17.0.8).  New project ("ng new Default"), no file changes.  No errors on "ng serve" but browser console shows:

`main.ts:5 ERROR Error: NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with 'runInInjectionContext'. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0203`

Are there other steps required to make the Hello World app run?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As per angular documentation, you are maybe using an incompatible version, could you try `node 18` instead!

[angular node version compatibility](https://angular.io/guide/versions)

| ANGULAR | NODE.JS | TYPESCRIPT | RXJS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 17.0.x | ^18.13.0 || ^20.9.0 | >=4.9.3 <5.3.0 | ^6.5.3 || ^7.4.0 |

Below is a working version, maybe you can match the versions of this stackblitz

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-bcphhu)

Comment: I uninstalled everything and reinstalled node 18.13.0.  Same error.  However, this is on a highly managed work machine, I also tried on a personal Windows machine and it worked fine.  Can AV and other security software interfere with node/angular?

Comment: @Frunobulax FIrewall/ proxy might be the issue mostly! but this is due to version mismatch, because if you check the stackblitz it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't change anything maybe the node version is causing the problem.
You can install the Node Version Manager which makes it easier to change on the fly Node versions.

https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm